# Kentico Event Calendars in multiple locations

Tags: kentico

I've been asked if the internal sales site i built can support multiple event calendars. What they would like is a calendar for each group and a global. So the global calendar will shows global and events from each group. The Group Calendars would only show their relevant events.

So i added folders to my Event node, and added some test pages. They show in the global event since it's path is ./%. Great.

For a group (Compliance), it's path is /events/compliance/%. This works, and the Compliance calendar only shows events in within the specified folder.

But.

Each event node's url is based on the global path so /event/compliance/event-1.aspx. This takes the user out of the group section and breaks the user flow. I'd like the group specific events to still apear with their URL stucture. So like this, /Our-Company/Compliance/Calendar-of-Events/event-1.aspx.

I could have the group specific events with their node, but then i loose all the vents on the global calendar. So is there a way for a single calendar to pull events from multiple locations within the tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options:

1. Use linked pages.  This would allow you to have a global location and simply have a "copy" in a different location (for navigation purposes really).  Nice part is if update one of those linked pages, it updates them all so no worries about outdated content.
2. Categorize your events.  Little more effort involved with this one but will work the same.
3. Set the WHERE statement to filter on the `NodeAliasPath`.  You'd do something like this

Path = /%
Where = "NodeAliasPath LIKE '/GlobalEvents/%' OR NodeAliasPath LIKE '/Groups/Compliance/Events/%'"

3 is probably your best bet and if you want to make it more dynamic you can use macros in your where condition.

Comment: Once again, thanks Brendan. For some reason '=' didn't work, but LIKE did. Here's the WHERE from my global location: NodeAliasPath LIKE '/Events/Global/%' OR
NodeAliasPath LIKE '/Our-Company/Compliance/Calendar-of-Events/%'

Comment: my next step is adding css classes based on parent node, or node alias, but that should be 'easy'.

Comment: I updated the answer @MarkHandy to include LIKE vs. =, my mistake.

Comment: Great. I have it working. Even updated the the transformation to give me css class based off the patent node ID. I'm using that to change the background colour from easy group identification.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Brenden especially #2.  #2 is going to give you the most flexibility and control over querying global items into multiple areas, but also gives you a single management location.  We use that method on almost all of our projects and is both easy to manage but also easy to teach your content contributors how to use it the best.

The only other recommendation I would give is also include some kind of flag field where you can prioritize those items on a calendar list view.  We often have a requirement that things do not only show up by date order, but also that certain calendar events take priority in sorting.  Where you might not use that upfront, having that available down the road is some good forward thinking.

Comment: I had thought of changing the pagetype from with a category selection, but with this group of editors, what i thought would/should have been simple isn't. Forcing content is specific folders or locations takes some of the guess work out. I have #3 from Brandon's solution working.

Comment: Thanks, just working on adding a class based of the node ID so i can alternate background colours on the global calendar. Thanks for the help.